# arm64 armv7 armv7s Architectures settings

Tags: ios

**Criteria:**

1. iPad only app.  Only support iPad 2 or later.
2. Want to take advantage of 64 bit code for the latest iPads.
3. Min iOS 6.
4. Xcode 5.02 with iOS 7 SDK (current release)

> Should I set both Architectures and Valid architectures to arm64 armv7
>   armv7s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** You can set both architectures for your above criteria. But problem is, you should handle code for both cases(32-bit & 64-bit).

**Note:**

Additional Notes for you.

1. You can support from Minimum IOS 5.1
2. You can use Xcode 5.0.1 with IOS 7 base SDK

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 5.0.1 can build your app with both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries included. This combined binary requires a minimum deployment target of iOS 5.1.1 or later. The 64-bit binary runs only on 64-bit devices running iOS 7.0.3 and later. If you have an existing app, you should first update your app for iOS 7 and then port it to run on 64-bit processors. By updating it first for iOS 7, you can remove deprecated code paths and use modern practices. If you’re creating a new app, target iOS 7 and compile 32-bit and 64-bit versions of your app.

The architecture for 64-bit apps on iOS is almost identical to the architecture for OS X apps, making it easy to create a common code base that runs in both operating systems. Converting a Cocoa Touch app to 64-bit follows a similar transition process as the one for Cocoa apps on OS X. Pointers and some common C types change from 32 bits to 64 bits. Code that relies on the NSInteger and CGFloat types needs to be carefully examined.

Start by building the app for the 64-bit runtime, fixing any warnings that occur as well as searching your code for specific 64-bit issues. For example:

Make sure all function calls have a proper prototype.
Avoid truncating 64-bit values by accidentally assigning them to a 32-bit data type.
Ensure that calculations are performed correctly in the 64-bit version of your app.
Create data structures whose layouts are identical in the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of your app (such as when you write a data file to iCloud).

Reference: [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thank you.  Very detail answer.  I saw several questions on SO where people encountered the CGFloat issues related to 64bit.